# Starting apache web server at every reboot cloud-init

Tags: linux, apache, cloud-init

I am pretty new in the cloud-init. I got VM everything is setup and running and I designed the reboot mechanism in the VM to use when VM requires reboot after installing updates. So when I reboot the VM Apache is not working by itself after reboot until I run the start command. Is there a way to make Apache start after every reboot?

Comment: How about using cloudinit to set up systemd or alike?

Comment: So I started to look at here but did you mean [this](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved, after reading this two sites

- [apache-server-doesnt-start-automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42190/apache-server-doesnt-start-automatically)
- [starting_apache_web_server_at_every_reboot_for_debian_ubuntu_linux](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/servers/apache_web_http_server/tips_and_tricks/starting_apache_web_server_at_every_reboot_for_debian_ubuntu_linux.php)

I added this line:

`cloud_config['runcmd'].append(['update-rc.d', 'apache2', 'enable'])`